# Why is function parameter always an lvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

I could not wrap my mind around the following statement from Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++...

> it's especially important to bear in mind that a parameter is always an
> lvalue, even if its type is an rvalue reference. That is given
>
> ```
> void f(Widget&& w);
> ```
>
> the paramter w is an lvalue, event it s type is
> rvalue-reference-to-widget.

How come a parameter w is an lvalue, but its type is rvalue-reference-to-widget? When people say w is an lvalue, doesnt that mean that its type is a lvalue type? I am probably missing something.

EDIT:
Mant thanks to those who commented...I am still a bit confused. I guess I dont fully understand the definition of these concept involved.
What are lvalue, rvalue, lvalue reference, rvalue reference? Are these part of the context free grammar of the c++ language? Do these have anything to with code generation? Can I think of type and value category two separate production rules in the c++ context free grammar? What do they mean?

Comment: The *type* of `w` is rvalue-reference-to-widget, but the *value category* of `w` is lvalue.

Comment: "event it s type ..." --> "even if its type ..."??

Comment: `w` is an lvalue because it has name. You can bind rvalue to it when you call this function, but `w` itself is an lvalue. It is confusing, I know :(

Comment: I suppose regarding to function context (the code inside function) the parameters are always defined, have lifetime from entrance to exit and therefore a priori considered as l-value. In other words they are not temporary i.e. “static” on function level.

Comment: What are these lvalue, rvalue, lvalue reference, rvalue reference? Are these part of the context free grammar of the c++ language? Or do these have to with code generation? Can I think of type and value category two separate production rules in the c++ context free grammar? What do they mean? I am really confused.

Comment: See this https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: @4xy thanks for sending me the link, but honestly i feel more confused now. What on earth do these mean? ```a glvalue (“generalized” lvalue) is an expression whose evaluation determines the identity of an object, bit-field, or function;
a prvalue (“pure” rvalue) is an expression whose evaluation... ```

Comment: For simplicity you can think of rvalue as of anonymous entity that lives until the semicolon on current line. The rest is the lvalue.

Comment: @4xy and how come something can be lvalue and rvalue reference at the same time?

Comment: The *r-value* in *r-value-reference* merely tells you what types can bind to it. Once a reference of any kind is bound it is an *l-value*.

Comment: The `w` lvalue parameter will be bound by the caller's rvalue argument (and only by an rvalue argument).

Answer (score 2):

The type of `w` is rvalue-reference as you can see in the error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

class Widget {};

void f(Widget&& w)
{
    std::cout << "HERE " << std::endl;
    return;
}

int main()
{
    Widget ww;
    //f(std::move(ww));
    f(ww);
    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T616cq

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'Widget&&' to lvalue of type 'Widget'
```

However the [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) of `w` is lvalue.

The following expressions are lvalue expressions: (bolding mine)

> **the name of a variable**, a function, a template parameter object (since
> C++20), or a data member, **regardless of type**, such as std::cin or
> std::endl. **Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference**, **the
> expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression**;